# Is it possible to get login history of user in Drupal 8

Tags: drupal, drupal-8

i have a user login panel in drupal 8 where i need to print a banner when user has been logged after 3 months, but when i access user last login iam getting current login, how is it possible in drupal 8?

Comment: Did you try the module Login history (https://www.drupal.org/project/login_history) ? I would then fetch the values from the new table and add the banner according your own condition(s).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check this module

https://www.drupal.org/project/login_history

This module adds a new table which stores information about individual user logins, including a timestamp, IP address, user agent information, and whether or not the login was via a reset password link.